Shapefile and Google Maps QGIS 3.34
I opened my shapefile which contains my fields.
I also opened QuickMapServices-Google Satellite
My fields are not shown in right place in Google Satellite. My fields are shown in the ocean...

What projection is your shapefile in? does it have a .prj file? you can open them in notepad

I have only .shp, .dbf, .shx

Since you only have .shp, .dbf and .shx files, then your ESRI Shapefile layer doesn't have a proper Coordinate Reference System definition. You need to define a proper CRS for such layer.
See:

Coordinate Reference System and Geometry
Define Shapefile projection

